xauthority or damaged partitions?
so my problem is that i deleted efi partition of my (let's say for better undrestanding) /dev/nvme01 250G and then i booted with my /dev/sda 120G in my mounted /dev/nvme01!! (i had a very busy day and didnt have time to figure this out). after a day or two i could not login to my mounted /dev/nvme01 and when i entered the password it looping and show me the login again and again... i thought this is the time i should figure my efi partition and boot directly to my /nvme01 instead of booting from sda and then nvme..
i installed the efi partition on nvme
the boot system clearly show that it can see the 250G nvme
but it cant boot from it.
i cant even boot from mounted /dev/nvme01 on sda any longer.
i think my only solution maybe is that i get a backup of /dev/nvme01 when im in my sda and then compeletly install a new ubuntu on nvme...
any other solution would be my savior.
thank you!

so i mounted my nvme on /mnt
i chroot it and install and update grub(updating was one thing i didnt try before)
then umnount
then reboot
and now i can see the login again but not my mouse nor my keyboard work!
the only thing that i figured is that clock is working so its def not a freeze!!
is this a nvidia thing??????

Grub does not have its own drivers for mouse & keyboard, it uses UEFI/BIOS as Ubuntu drivers not yet installed. Check settings in UEFI for USB full support or an enable USB mouse/keyboard setting or similar setting. Each UEFI vendor has slightly different settings.

@oldfred oh intresting.. however i installed a new ubuntu due to login loop...i think i pretty much f^&*cked my hardwared... ways to learn new things LOL. thank you
